# Tomboy notes aren't searchable from Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, tomboy

I installed Tomboy and created an example note.

Trying to search both the title (first line) and the content didn't give any results.

I was expecting the notes to show up after searching for them, because there is a Dash plugin specifically named 'Tomboy' that is supposed to enable just that.

Is there something I am missing? Any additional lenses I should enable, or tabs I should look into?

This is the screenshot of the plugin (down below, in the 'Dash plugins' section):

[image]

Comment: There were times when I was able to search my Tomboy notes through the Dash, sync them with an iPhone app called "WebNotes" using Ubuntu One... those days are gone. I'm using Evernote now.

Comment: @speter And does Evernote supports Dash integration and sync with Android?

Comment: There is no native Evernote app for Ubuntu, but you can install Everpad, which is using the Evernote API and lets you sync your notes with your Evernote account. In previous Ubuntu versions (I think before Smart Scopes came along), there was an Everpad Lens for the Dash. In 14.04, you can only search notes through the app's GUI. The most recent notes can also be found by using the app-indicator in the Unity panel. About Android, I can only guess, but I guess there's plenty of Evernote apps in the Play Store.